# How to use content projection (aka transclusion) in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-components

I am new to angular 4.

I have a doubt in angular 4 embedded components.

example:

```
<hero-list>
    <hero></hero>
    <hero></hero>
</hero-list>
```

I wanted to know how to create a view based on this structure that is embedding component inside another component.

Comment: Do you have already write some code and can you post some code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `<ng-content></ng-content>` in your `hero-list`-component. So you can realize your wish above.

**hero-list.component.html**

```
<div class="hero-list">
  <h1>Hero list</h1>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

And now you can wrap your `hero-item`-components and they will be printed inside of `hero-list`component.

**app.component.html**

```
<hero-list>
  <hero-item></hero-item>
  <hero-item></hero-item>
</hero-list>
```

Here is working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nvpmtc

And [here](https://alligator.io/angular/content-projection-angular/) is a good article about content projection in angualr.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you want a master layout with sub views, you might want to look at the Angular router https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5

Which might look something like this

```
<app-component>
  <h1>Static title</h1>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</app-component>
```

The router-outlet will switch between different components defined in your routing file when navigating to different links, but the html around it won't change