# Is it possible to have HTML content inside an Angular Component?

Tags: angular, html, angular-components

I'm trying to create a reusable tabs  component in Angular looking something like this:

```
<ng-tabs>
    <ng-tab>
        <div class="title">title</div>
        <div class="content">content</div>
    <ng-tab>
    <ng-tab>
        <div class="title">title</div>
        <div class="content">content</div>
    <ng-tab>
</ng-tabs>
```

In this case, `ng-tabs` is a component that passes toggle controls to the nested component `ng-tab` and the latter is just a holder for any content. It could be just text or buttons or whatever. In this case you would import tabs component and use it just like it's shown above.

The problem is that angular blocks whatever you put inside the opening and closing tags off the component. It doesn't behave like a normal HTML element which accepts cold nodes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use content projection (aka transclusion) in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45752761/how-to-use-content-projection-aka-transclusion-in-angular)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that what you need is to add `<ng-content></ng-content>` into your ng-tab.component.html where you want to show the content of your tab tag:

```
<div class="myTab">
   <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

[-For more info](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-transclusion-using-ng-content)